# Talend : Dealing with empty rows while copying from Excel to SQL

Tags: sql, excel, talend

I am copying data to my SQL table from Excel sheet. Excel sheet has 12 records and other 2000 empty rows.
My job workflow is Excel input -> tMap -> tMSSqlOutput.

Problem is when I execute my job it is reading 2000 rows from the input. Later empty rows are not getting copied to my SQL table as there is 'NOT NULL' value check.

But I want my job to stop reading those empty rows from Excel input itself, how do I do that?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should add a tFilterRow component to your flow like:
tFileInputExcel->tFilterRow->tMap->tMSSqlOutput

You should then configure a condition in the filter component. Choose a column that always has a value and add as a condition that this should have length greater than one.
Your flow should look like : [image: this]